# Apache rewrite condition: apply to multiple independent rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^alpha(.*) https://alpha.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^bravo(.*) https://bravo.sample.edu/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^charlie(.*) https://sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want the condition to apply to each rule, but it only applies to the first rule. As written, the rewrite rule for bravo will match even if the request host is not foo.bar.com.

The only way I've seen to do this is to repeat condition for each rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^alpha(.*) https://alpha.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^bravo(.*) https://bravo.sample.edu/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^charlie(.*) https://sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there a way to do this without repeating the condition for each rule?

Comment: A `RewriteCond` is _always_ only applied to the rule following it. That is a documented and intended behavior. What you _can_ do is to implement an exception before your actual rule which has a condition and ends rewriting or performs a rewrite to something else. Then the following rules will get applied only if the first, single condition does _not_ get applied.

Comment: You could negate your condition, and have it followed by a rule that does no actual rewriting, but uses the [`S`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) flag to skip the next three rules.